# image source changing at the wrong time after a few minutes in a slide show

Tags: javascript, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

I'm a designer more than a programmer, but I'm trying to get the hang of javascript so I have more design options when it comes to web design beyond plugins.  So here's the problem I'm having.

I have a page with 4 slide shows. Right now I have it so that when one of 4 buttons are clicked it will change the array it gets the image sources from and loop through the images every 4 sec.

At first the slideshows look fine and the change happens when the image is hidden, but after a couple minutes the source change falls out of time with the fading effects and happens when its visible.  It also works fine to have the shows switch with no problem.

All the timing and variables get reset and the new parameter from the `onClick`-call switches which array is used.  I tried one solution where I made the image change part it's own function and called it from other functions to control the timing more, but then for some reason `clearTimeout` stopped working to clear the loop and it would still play one instance of the loop at the same time as another.

Maybe someone can look at this code and see a simple fix for the timing issue.

```
i=0
var delay=4000
var fade=1000
var timer;

function play(showNum){
    var showNum = showNum; 
    $("#show").stop(true,true)
    newShow(); 
    changeInfo(showNum);
    $("#show").hide();
    change(showNum);
}

function change(showNum){
    $("#show").fadeIn(fade);
    $("#show").attr("src",showNum[i]);
    i = (i+1)% showNum.length;
    $("#show").delay(delay-(fade*2)).fadeOut(fade);
    timer=setTimeout (function(){change(showNum)},delay)
}

function newShow(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    i=0;
}
```

Here is an update to the code since I posted this.

```
function play(showNum){
var showNum = showNum; 
$("#show").stop(true,true);
newShow(); 
$("#show").hide();
changeInfo(showNum);
change(showNum);
$("#show").fadeIn(fade);
setTimeout(function(){loop(showNum);},fade*2);
}
function loop(showNum){
$("#show").fadeOut(fade);
setTimeout (function(){change(showNum);},fade);
$("#show").fadeIn(fade);
int=setTimeout (function(){loop(showNum);},delay);
}

function change(showNum){
$("#show").attr("src",showNum[i]);
i = (i+1)% showNum.length;
}

function newShow(){
 clearTimeout(int);
 i=0;
}
```

I don't get a problem with the timing anymore, but I do get a weird hiccup if I click on a new slideshow when it's on fadeOut where it changes image then changes back and then fades in with the next image of the previous slide show then fades out and starts the right slide show from there.

Comment: Is this exactly your code? In change(), `timmer` should be `timer`

Comment: O yeah sorry.  I realized I misspelled "timer" as "timmer" and wanted to change that before I submitted the post but I guess I missed one.  In the code they were all "timmer." I'll fix that in case anyone else looks at it.